# Woman prayer book

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, prayer-book

If I would like to buy a Siddur or book with prayers specifically written for woman (and about woman related topics) which English-Hebrew book is the best option to go with?

Comment: Could you specify what nusach you want it in? (Ashkenaz, Sfard, Edot HaMizrach)

Answer (score 2):

Aliza Lavie compiled a [nice collection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385522746) of prayers specifically for women and women related topics (amongst other contemporary inserts and prayers).

Comment: Who downvoted this??? +1

Answer (score 1):

Artscroll has a sidur specificly writen for women, which i found to be well writen with the specific laws for women.

Also there is a popular sefer called "Aneini", which contains many tefilos for specific occasions. I am of the impression that it's target audience are women.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85240/9682

Answer (score 1):

[Eichlers.com](http://www.eichlers.com/) has the following items for women.

[Tefillas Channah](http://www.eichlers.com/tefillas-channah-prayers-for-the-jewish-woman-hardcover.html) from Feldheim.

[Siddur Ohel Sarah](http://www.eichlers.com/women-s-siddur-ohel-sarah-the-klein-ed-hebrew-english-complete-ultra-white-hardcover-full-size-ashkenaz.html) from Artscroll.

Comment: I must say a lot of people hate the Siddur Ohel Sarah, because it omits Tachanun and stuff (which women generally do not say) but it acts as if those parts don't exist. I'm not a woman, so I can't complain, but still.

Comment: @Ezra: If the lady wants a full Siddur then she can buy any Siddur that is available. If she wants a Siddur geared for women this is a good choice. If she feels that there are things omitted that should have been included she can publish a Siddur with what she feels is important.

Comment: @gersho why is it a good choice if it omits parts of davening?? Maybe it's the only choice, but that doesn't make it a good one. Perhaps someone will publish a good women's Siddur soon, and in the meantime we should call a spade a spade. The OP wanted a Siddur with prayers specifically for women, not a Siddur that leaves out half of davening on the assumption that all women are too busy with children to pray. Is there any prayer in there which is specifically written for women, as the OP requested?

Comment: @ezra wouldn't you also expect an outcry if a chasidic siddur omitted tachanun because they generally don't say it? it's ok to publish an abridged siddur with just the most common/important prayers, but you have to admit that's what you're doing.